# Remove a property keys from all node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I  download a dataset from the internet. But dataset has some unwanted properties. Because of that my dataset is huge. basically, I want to filter the database.

I would like to remove a property key from all node

```
      "start": {
"identity": 0,
"labels": [
          "Node"
        ],
"properties": {
"x": "10.6056248",
"y": "47.1732157",
"street_count": "3"
        }
      },
      "relationship": {
"identity": 0,
"start": 0,
"end": 20,
"type": "RELATED",
"properties": {
"ref": "A12",
"osmid": "[103276220, 103271459, 453545145, 10110984, 204103464, 29034282, 204103467, 204016338, 23966515, 103276217, 59757436, 204016351]",
"length": 3685.591999999999,
"name": "Inntal Autobahn",
"maxspeed": "130",
"lanes": "['3', '2']",
"geometry": "LINESTRING (10.6056248 47.1732157, 10.6077387 47.1734722, 10.6082515 47.1735344, 10.6085156 47.1735707, 10.6088688 47.1736191, 10.6094483 47.1737172, 10.6099849 47.1738187, 10.6107471 47.1740115, 10.6114325 47.1742194, 10.6120899 47.174459, 10.6127578 47.1747469, 10.6133762 47.1750513, 10.6141991 47.1755512, 10.614311 47.1756329, 10.6148323 47.1760134, 10.615342 47.1764467, 10.6157925 47.1769004, 10.6165099 47.1778069, 10.6171836 47.1787272, 10.6175571 47.1791516, 10.6178384 47.1794141, 10.6181845 47.179737, 10.6186197 47.1800941, 10.6191062 47.1804327, 10.6195835 47.1807353, 10.6201042 47.1810176, 10.6206844 47.1812917, 10.621312 47.181545, 10.6219279 47.1817632, 10.6225722 47.1819513, 10.6229524 47.1820501, 10.623216 47.1821156, 10.6237939 47.18225, 10.6252743 47.182581, 10.6264776 47.1828521, 10.6275371 47.1830966, 10.6291987 47.1834975, 10.6297891 47.1836426, 10.6321448 47.1842436, 10.6352364 47.1850876, 10.6353627 47.1851255, 10.6366729 47.1855098, 10.6380716 47.1859653, 10.6392968 47.1864251, 10.6400879 47.1867654, 10.6409802 47.1872101, 10.6411455 47.1873033, 10.641467 47.1874799, 10.6420809 47.1878655, 10.6425598 47.1882012, 10.6430794 47.1886174, 10.6435366 47.1890316, 10.6439666 47.189484, 10.6443888 47.190006, 10.644528 47.1901931, 10.6446988 47.1904546, 10.6448142 47.1906353)",
"bridge": "yes",
"highway": "motorway",
"oneway": "True"
        }
      },
      "end": {
"identity": 20,
"labels": [
          "Node"
        ],
"properties": {
"x": "10.6448142",
"y": "47.1906353",
"ref": "140",
"street_count": "3",
"highway": "motorway_junction"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "length": 1.0
}
{
```

[image]
I try this but not working

```
MATCH (n) REMOVE n.osmid
```

Comment: Why is it not working? what is the error?

Comment: no error.. just a empty table.

Comment: Have you run `MATCH (n) RETURN COUNT(n.osmid)` afterwards? What you call "empty table" might just be an empty visualization since `MATCH (n) REMOVE n.osmid` does not return anything, so there is nothing to display.

Comment: ` MATCH (n) WHERE EXISTS(n.osmid) RETURN DISTINCT "node" as entity, n.osmid AS osmid LIMIT 25 UNION ALL MATCH ()-[r]-() WHERE EXISTS(r.osmid) RETURN DISTINCT "relationship" AS entity, r.osmid AS osmid LIMIT 25 `  this query is not empty

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have the osmid on your relationship and not on your nodes actually. The query to remove properties from a relationship is:

```
MATCH ()-[r]->()
REMOVE r.osmid
```